# How to automatically show programs when opening an unknown file

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to tweak windows 7 so that I could automatically see list of  programs to open an unknown file when I double click on them?

Answer (score 2):

You can right click the file and select Open with ...
If you don't see the option then press and hold Shift key and the Open with... option should be displayed.